# Hive displays problems after ambari is installed

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive

I installed a ambari cluster, but when I use the server hive command link hive, the page is displayed, but in my CDH cluster and native hive here should hive without 0: jdbc:hive2://master.ambari:2181,slave1.amb , how should I set to let him become a hive, or JDBC is shown here:0:jdbc:hive2://master.ambari:2181,slave1.amb. What is the cause of the amb? I look forward to your help. Thank you.

```
[root@slave1 conf]# hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://master.ambari:2181,slave1.ambari:2181,slave2.ambari:2181/default;password=root;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;user=root;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2
20/07/20 21:52:18 [main]: INFO jdbc.HiveConnection: Connected to slave1.ambari:10000
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 3.1.0.3.1.4.0-315)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 3.1.0.3.1.4.0-315)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
Beeline version 3.1.0.3.1.4.0-315 by Apache Hive
0: jdbc:hive2://master.ambari:2181,slave1.amb>
```

Answer (score 0):

`amb` is the domain name you gave to the servers in your cluster.

`beeline` is the new connection CLI, not `hive` (which is only an alias)

What you see is correct, and I'm not sure what documentation you're referring to, but seems like it's out of date

Comment: I always thought there was something wrong with my installation. It turned out to be normal. Thank you